# Can I link to an embedded file in a PDF with Reportlab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Is it possible place a link in a PDF with Reportlab so that when it is selected, it opens a file that is embedded in the PDF? I want to place links throughout a PDF that reference small files (similar to .txt files). I don't want all the links to break whenever the relative path to the files is no longer valid. I just want the text files to be embedded in the PDF so I can give the PDF to someone and the links will always work to open the different files.